# Why use the Accessed-Bit for the Least-Recently-Used algorithm?

Tags: lru, page-replacement

In our lecture, the LRU algorithm for page replacement was explained by looking wether a page has been accessed in the last "epoch" (not sure if that's the proper english term). After every epoch, the A-Bit is set back to 0 on all pages. Lazy me didn't listen correctly and implemented a simulator in a different manner during an assignment:

Just put the most recently used page on top of a stack so we have our pages in the order in which they were most recently used and it's obvious that both ideas are aquivalent.

This is done this way on wikipedia too so I'm wondering, why would you even do it the A-Bit-way? Is it just a naive implementation from the past or does it have better runtime? I would doubt that since you'd have those epochs and reset the A-Bit all the time.

Comment: How do you know which pages were the most recently used?  Typically the hardware does not record this information.  The A-bit is all the data you get.

Comment: There's another issue with your approach: what do you do when a page which is already on the stack is accessed again?  If you want to move it to the top of the stack, you have to search through the stack to find and delete the previous occurrence, which takes time.  If you duplicate it, the amount of memory used for your stack grows rapidly to infinity.

Comment: @NateEldredge The pages are being called somewhere, so that call can be noted, right? It seems way more efficient to me

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "call".

Comment: @NateEldredge My page didnt refresh so I didnt see your second comment :D I guess that's problematic, yeah.  And by call I mean, whenever a page has to be accessed.

Comment: Think about what the CPU is doing.  When the application accesses a page that's already mapped into memory, it can't trap to the OS every time to let your algorithm know about it; that would slow down the application by thousands of times.  Whatever is going to be done, has to be done by the hardware itself, and it has to be very simple and fast because it may happen on every single instruction.  Setting a bit in the page table is about the most you can hope for, and that's all that you get on any CPU that I know of.

Comment: Alright, this makes more sense. We rarely talk about performance of such operations in my lectures, so that's really helpful